# Facebook Connect - App to display personal and friend pictures

Tags: facebook

I have been asked to scope a app which would pull out tagged images of a user and his/her friends.  I've no idea how easy/difficult this would be to attempt or where to begin but understand that it may be possible via Connect?

I've had a search around and can't find much info - so I wonder whether anyone can offer any advice/ point me in the right direction?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Are you looking for iPhone of for android solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to accomplish.

For connecting it's easy using: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

They even have an FQL table you can query that has the photo tags. See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/